# Accepting or Declining MacOS Calendar / iCal events with Automator

Tags: automator, calendar, ical, google-calendar

**Problem**
With Automator, you can select a list of Calendar events via filtering or search. There is an Automator Library action to *delete* calendar events. However, as far as I can tell, there is no way to *decline* calendar events. I don't want to delete events; I want to decline them.

Is there an action to modify the response to a Calendar invite (vs deleting it)?

In the example below, I'm able to delete all of the listed items, including one that someone else invited me to. In my real calendar, the same script does not even delete certain meetings and I can't figure out why. (Although that's still not the desired outcome.)

[image]

**Background / Use Case**

I am extremely scheduled at work; most of my job is going to meetings. I wanted to add several weeks of upcoming vacations, conferences, and offsites to my calendar. Google's new calendar UI kills the "Busy / automatically decline events" Labs feature. I also will have to manually decline several hundred events. I was looking for a way to do this in bulk; unable to find any calendar bulk editing tools, I tried Automator.